# zend framework 2.3 check session before loading module

Tags: session, zend-framework2

I am using zend framework 2.3 and authenticate user by AuthenticationService.
Now I want to load other module only if user authenticated. How To check user identity before loading module?

Comment: are you using zfcuser?

Comment: No.
I am using this code

use Zend\Authentication\Result;

use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;

use Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session as SessionStorage;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter as DbAdapter;

use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable as AuthAdapter;

and authenticate user by 
$authAdapter = new AuthAdapter($dbAdapter,
             'tbl_admin', 
             'user_name',
             'user_password', 
             "MD5(?) " 
            );
$authAdapter
 ->setIdentity($data['user_name'])
 ->setCredential($data['user_password'])
;

$auth = new AuthenticationService();

Comment: Your code block should be formatted with markdown. It's too hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic use case for ACLs. You can define a role for your user, and a resource for your module. It's exactly what you're up to. I suggest you use the BjyAuthorize implementation.

https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize